# How do I add a video in an iphone application?

Tags: iphone

How do I add a video in my iphone application?

I just want to show a video in 1st screen.

Comment: Please elaborate - what application, have you any code?

Answer (score 0):

use The [MPMoviePlayerController](http://developer.apple.com/iPhone/library/documentation/MediaPlayer/Reference/MPMoviePlayerController_Class/MPMoviePlayerController/MPMoviePlayerController.html) class supports video playback in either H.264 (Baseline Profile Level 3.0) format or MPEG-4 Part 2 video (Simple Profile) format. Playback is full-screen

Here you go for [tutor](http://developer.apple.com/IPhone/library/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/AudioandVideoTechnologies/AudioandVideoTechnologies.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH19-SW12)

This General Way  :

iPhone can not support all format files.It can support MP4 format.You can lear more from: http://www.apple.com If the video is mp4 format.You can directly transfer the video to iPhone using iTunes.If the video is not mp4 format.You need a convert software to help you convert the video to MP4 format.And then transfer the video that be converted to iTunes.I always use iskysoft iPhone Moive converter.You can download it from: http://www.iskysoft.com/iphone-movie-converter-windows.html

Comment: I wouldn't say its primarily for game developers. There are many other cases where one might want to show a full screen video.